# Google Sheets Script To Check Changes From One Sheet File To Update Another Sheet URL

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Apologies if something like this has already been asked, I have little to no experience with this.

Is there script that can check a Google Sheets workbook for edits to then affect a different Sheets workbook. I have found something along these lines but it always references the same workbook and moves the entire row.

I have a spreadsheet that contains multiple lists of users (Sample Move) and another staff member has a sheet containing activity status and other details (Sample Edit). When a user is placed on the Sample Edit spreadsheet, they would then need to be moved from their respective Active list and moved to the corresponding Inactive list. Users would not need to be automatically added back to the active list once they return, that would be a manual process.

Link to example Sample Move: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q3yRMa5sum8dHLyw_2ppLaWBUEoj_Gl6F_btWIiqsfw/edit?usp=sharing

Link to example Sample Edit: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IZzoJQkFsavgnjkwz1GkuwDj-m6kG-CYQfLKx2EmPSI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Oh I suppose I missed that most important part, editing the post.

Comment: Sorry , I did not fully understand what you want to do. Particularly this statement "When a user is placed on the Sample Edit spreadsheet, they would then need to be moved from their respective Active list and moved to the corresponding Inactive list". Can you show your expected output? I checked your sample edit where user zeep and don't exist. But in your Sample move sheet user don't is still in active list? It should be moved to Inactive list right?

Comment: In addition, Do you intend to have a fixed number of possible users for your active and inactive list? only 7 users? or do you plan to adjust it in the future

Comment: The Sample Move contains all the users, the Sample Edit list would be a list of users that have been deactivated, with a reactivation date if they return (our staff wants to keep them there, even once they return for some reason). If a user is added to the Sample Edit, I would need them to automatically be moved on the Sample Move workbook from the active list to the inactive list. My sample output is zeep, ID 2222222. Zeep was added to the Sample Edit, and moved from Active1 to Inactive1 on Sample Move.

Comment: ID 978645 was added to Sample Edit, which would mean they had been moved from Active2 to Inactive2 on Sample Move. But they had returned, so they have been manually moved back to Active2 already.

Comment: Another question. Is it safe to assume that if for example ID 978645 deactivated again. You will include another row item for ID 978645? or you will edit existing details in Sample Edit Sheeet?

Comment: We have done both before. The current method would be each user is added when they get deactivated, then the reactivation date is added if they return. If the user goes inactive again, the date gets updated without adding a new entry. In the past the user was added each time they were inactive. Either method works.